# hibernate not able to create tables in sql server

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I am trying to connect through hibernate but it is not able to create table if I create table in sql server by manually then select,insert and delete query is working fine, I am using following setting in hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:sqlserver://shokumar-idc\JDESSELOCAL;databaseName=scart</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">JDE</property>
        <property name="connection.password">JDE</property>
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

        <mapping class="dao.tables.User" />
        <mapping class="dao.tables.Product" />
        <mapping class="dao.tables.Orderitems" />
        <mapping class="dao.tables.Order" />
        <mapping class="dao.tables.Category" />
        <mapping class="dao.tables.Config" />
        <mapping class="dao.tables.Adminuser" />
        <mapping class="dao.tables.Cities" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: Why do you use the HSQLDialect with SQLServer?

Comment: I tried with sql server dialect (org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect) also but same result...

Comment: I found out it was sql server permission issue after giving permission it woking fine thanks a lot for your help